# Hide image after a particular time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an image that I need to hide an image after showing it for a particular interval. I wrote the following code for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="./1_files/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div').delay(2000).show(0);
$('hide').delay(3000).hide(0);​
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="hide" src="9.png" width="29" height="39">
</body>
</html>
```

The image is not hiding. It keeps getting displayed. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps because the selector should be `#hide`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery 1.7, it works just fine for me with this minor correction/change:

```
$("#hide").delay(3000).hide(1);​
```

The two changes I made were:

1. Fix your selector by adding the #
2. Add a minor time value to `.hide(1)` which turns it into an animation that works with `.delay()`.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NGW8p/

Comment: @www.AppTec.net - Look in your error console.  You have a syntax error so your javascript isn't even executing.  You also need to use `$(document).ready()` if your script is going to run before the document loads (which it is in your page).  And, there's no reason to use your the self executing function you are using.  That is only useful when you have things you want to limit the scope of.

Comment: It does not display or mention any error. Can you please point out.

Comment: Your page works fine for me here when I use `document.ready()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vcwKM/.  Here's a screenshot of your javascript error in the Chrome dev tools: http://content.screencast.com/users/jfriend/folders/Jing/media/09ef1eeb-c986-4f93-9f71-6f77b91128e4/2012-05-18_1644.png.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the problem

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

"Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue."